# How to retrieve details from Activity Logs from rundeck

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, rundeck

I am trying to create a dashboard for my Rundeck

I want to Have no of jobs executed, passed ,Failed, Terminated which is available in Activity log in Rundeck tool. But that cannot be downloaded in excel sheet..[Here is the Dashboard Format , i am Looking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQvGe.png)

I want to download the data on basis of day, weekly and monthly and then use tableau to create a dashboard. let me know

or is their anyway i can integrate my rundeck and tableau directly and create a similar dashboard

Answer (score 0):

You can get all those data from API, (for example getting [execution info](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html#execution-info)):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="localhost"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="nMp0uRsNUAH0w17JXxoDPqoBq6V4mB2O"

# specific api call info
execution="2"

# get the job forecast
curl -s --location --request GET "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/execution/$execution" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" | jq
```

Output:

```json
{
  "id": 2,
  "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/execution/2",
  "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/execution/show/2",
  "status": "succeeded",
  "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
  "executionType": "user",
  "user": "admin",
  "date-started": {
    "unixtime": 1606853136420,
    "date": "2020-12-01T20:05:36Z"
  },
  "date-ended": {
    "unixtime": 1606853136878,
    "date": "2020-12-01T20:05:36Z"
  },
  "job": {
    "id": "900a885b-576c-4c8c-a118-4bd1bf775c7b",
    "averageDuration": 458,
    "name": "Test",
    "group": "",
    "project": "ProjectEXAMPLE",
    "description": "",
    "href": "http://localhost:4440/api/36/job/900a885b-576c-4c8c-a118-4bd1bf775c7b",
    "permalink": "http://localhost:4440/project/ProjectEXAMPLE/job/show/900a885b-576c-4c8c-a118-4bd1bf775c7b"
  },
  "description": "echo $LANG [... 2 steps]",
  "argstring": null,
  "serverUUID": "bd2d85ef-f9f9-4805-b51c-a4bbcf5875e3",
  "successfulNodes": [
    "localhost"
  ]
}
```

And if you want to filter you can use any JSON parser tool, on my example I have used [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) (`jq -r .status` to get the status of execution):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# protocol
protocol="http"

# basic rundeck info
rdeck_host="localhost"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="36"
rdeck_token="nMp0uRsNUAH0w17JXxoDPqoBq6V4mB2O"

# specific api call info
execution="2"

# get the job forecast
curl -s --location --request GET "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/execution/$execution" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" | jq -r .status
```

Output:

```sh
succeeded
```

So, checking the Tableau documentation, you can send your results via Tableau [API](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api.htm). In fact, you can use [Server API Client](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/) (python) to do this, maybe is a good idea to use some Rundeck job to send that data to Tableau via Tableau API on any python [script step](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63741605/10426011).

Comment: Thanks , was able to achieve the above, when it comes to taking data for monthly or weekly this is not working, can you help? 


``` #!/bin/sh

protocol="http"

rdeck_host="machinexyz.local"
rdeck_port="4440"
rdeck_api="35"
rdeck_token="token"
rdeck_project="projectRun"
xy="1w"

curl -s --location --request GET "$protocol://$rdeck_host:$rdeck_port/api/$rdeck_api/project/$rdeck_project/$xy" \
  --header "Accept: application/json" \
  --header "X-Rundeck-Auth-Token: $rdeck_token" ```